# Est-ce correct de ne pas accorder le verbe "enseigner" dans la phrase: "elle s'est enseigné les maths"?

Tags: grammaire, orthographe, conjugaison, compléments, francais-classique

J'ai cherché sur Internet la construction du verbe *enseigner* qui est celle-ci: ***enseigner quelque chose à quelqu'un***. Donc on est d'accord que *quelqu'un* est COI...

Or, quand je regardait la conjugaison du verbe s'enseigner, j'ai aperçu que le verbe s'accorde (elle s'est enseigné**e**,...)

Mais ce n'est-il pas [elle a enseigné **à** elle-même], et non pas [elle a enseigné elle-même]? Par conséquent la phrase *elle s'est enseigné**e*** est fausse non? Car l'auxiliaire *enseigné* ne doit pas s'accorder avec "s" puisque c'est un COI.

Ma question est donc pourquoi ce verbe sous forme pronominale s'accorde avec le sujet?

Est cela juste une erreur ou il y a-t-il une explication?

Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non, l'accord ne se fait pas dans ce cas; la raison est qu'il y a un COD (maths) et qu'il se trouve après le verbe.

- Elle s'est enseigné les maths (*« s' » est COI.*)
- Les maths qu'elle s'est enseigné sont d'un niveau élémentaire (*« s' » est COI.*)

En pratique¹ on trouvera plutôt ce qui suit parce que la règle du COI est très mal appliquée.

- Les maths qu'elle s'est enseigné**es** sont d'un niveau élémentaire ((*Il y a un COD et il est avant.*)

comparer

- elle s'est permis de faire une réflexion (*« s' » est COI.*)
- (*en pratique¹*) elle s'est permise de faire une réflexion (*action faite sur le sujet, pas de COD*)
- elle s'est permis une réflexion (*« s' » est COI ; pas d'accord*)
- (*en pratique¹*) elle s'est permis une réflexion (*COD, mais après, pas d'accord*)
- la réflexion qu'elle s'est permis (*« s' » est COI ; pas d'accord*)
- (*en pratique¹*) la réflexion qu'elle s'est permise (*COD, placé avants, accord*)
- Elle s'est pris**e** d'amitié pour son voisin (*action faite sur le sujet*)
- Elle s'est pris une crème glacée (*COD après*)
- la marque nette de la balle **qu**'elle s'est pris**e** en pleine tête (*COD avant*)

[L'accord du participe passé des verbes pronominaux](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/l-accord-du-participe-passe-des-verbes-pronominaux-188.php).

---

- Or, quand **j'ai regardé** la conjugaison du verbe s'enseigner, **je me suis aperçu** que le verbe s'accorde (elle s'est enseignée,...)

Les tableaux de conjugaison ne comprennent pas tous les cas, mais celui-ci comporterait en fait une erreur si on applique la règle du COI.

---

¹<sub>En pratique la règle du COI n'est souvent pas appliquée et la règle du COD la supplante ; ceci peut être conclu à partir d'un examen des pages suivantes ;  comparer l'ensemble des deux pages « [elle s'est permis**e** de, 1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22elle%20s%27est%20permise%20de%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) »
et « [elle s'est permis**e** de, 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22elle+s%27est+permise+de%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=-nOtYqnxI5CjlwSj_JLwAg&start=100&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwip1sn3srb4AhWQ0YUKHSO-BC4Q8tMDegQIARBD&biw=970&bih=999&dpr=1) »  à la page  « [elle s'est permis de](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22elle%20s%27est%20permis%20de%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) ».</sub>

Comment: Pour la phrase "elle s'est permise de faire une réflexion", je crois que c'est "permis" et pas "permise" car la construction est [permettre à qqu'un de faire qqch]. Il y a le "à" donc 's' est COI, alors on ne l'accorde pas non? Et puis, je ne pense pas que "enseigné" ne s'accorde pas non plus: "[...]tout comme elle s'est enseignée" car c'est elle a enseigné à elle même, donc 's' est COI.

Comment: Pour plus d'information, voici quelques exemples que j'ai trouvé: (https://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/elle+s%27est+permis+de+faire)    "Elle s'est permis de faire un discours super drôle" et "Il s'est permis de déterminer qu'un meurtre est mieux que deux meurtres".                                                                                  Bonne journée.

Comment: @Eren8hisfather  C'est exact, « elle s'est permis » est correct selon la règle du COI, et, évidemment, cela vaut aussi pour « enseigné ». Néanmoins, il y a  un problème très important, la règle du COI n'est pratiquement pas appliquée, ce qui fait qu'à la lecture on n'apprend pas la règle, ou plutôt, qu'on la désapprend ; mais, de toute façon, je vais suivre votre  correction et faire un changement, toutefois en précisant que, malheureusement, cette règle n'est presque pas suivie. Désolé de la contrariété que j'ai pu vous causer, merci d'avoir insisté (ma réponse est meilleure maintenant).